# Decentraland Preview in local struck at 88%

Tags: decentraland

Hi I'm doing the below steps

Installed the decentraland SDK

$ node -v
v16.0.0

$ npm -v
8.13.2

$ dcl -v
3.11.0

created a new scene with `dcl init`

Installed the dependencies.

$dcl start

application started.

When we load the preview it is struck forever.

with reaching 88% waited for an hour

the scene did not load

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue last week too, tried again this morning and looks like they've put out an update for the decentraland-ecs package

6.11.2 -> 6.11.3

Running `npm install decentraland-ecs@latest` in my local project has fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the local dev instance will hang at a certain point. You should try refreshing a few times while the browser is active. I'm not sure why, but sometimes if you have the tab open in the background, it will not fully load.

Also make sure that if you are calling/modifying a Transform, that it already exists on the entity. This will sometimes hang and not give a proper error.

So if you call `myEntity.getComponent(Transform).position = new Vector3(8,0,8)` before you add a Transform to the entity with `myEntity.addComponent(Transform)` this annoying non-error will happen and leave you scratching your head.